# Raster terrain curvature analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, terrain, curvature

When QGIS performs a curvature analysis of the terrain raster, which curvature analysis does this represent i.e. the [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) curvature analysis, or [Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature) curvature analysis?

[Understanding curvature filter of QGIS raster terrain analysis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27155) is a similar question, where [@whuber gave an extensive reply](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27158/65002) on how the curvature analysis is performed.

However what I still do not understand is whether or not the curvature analysis of the terrain raster is always a Gaussian curvature analysis, and never Mean curvature analysis.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because it is effectively asking three questions i.e. the same question for each of the three products.  Consequently, I think you should focus this question on the product that you want to know about the most, and then if you need to know about the others still, simply research/ask about them separately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply PolyGeo.
It would be unbelievable if QGIS, ArcGIS and SAGA would all use different curvature analysis types. They probably all use either Gaussian or Mean curvature type.
But as you are the Moderator, I complied with your request and changed the upper content to QGIS only.

Comment: For answers, see also https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2016-September/074993.html and https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2016-September/074998.html